# How to deserialize JSON into a List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> set

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, javascriptserializer

I have some JSON data :-

```
{
    "mail":"mitch@domain.com",
    "givenName":"User",
    "sn":"Name",
    "uid":"mitch",
    "gecos":"User Name"
}
```

What I'm trying to do is de-serialize this into a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`

I would normally do a dictionary, however some key's may be duplicated - this is the representation that is automatically generated by .NET when I pass a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` object into the `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` class.

When I just plug the serialized object into the   `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptDeserializer` I get a empty response back.

Comment: you have to make a List of type what i think

Comment: `however some key's may be duplicated` I can not think of such a json. Any example?

Comment: I don't think that would be a valid JSON anyway. Can you change the JSON format into an array of objects?

Comment: I am thinking just two more sections { "memberOf" : "groupA", "memberOf" : "groupB" }

Comment: @Brizio this is generated using the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer class, although it is not recommended, unfortuantley it is still 'in spec' as such according to http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf its a SUGGESTED to be unique not a MUST - slightly annoying I know

Comment: @JohnMitchell, I tried to serialize a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` and I'm getting something like `[{"Key":"memberOf","Value":"groupA"},{"Key":"memberOf","Value":"groupB"}]`, which version of the assembly are you using?

Comment: @JohnMitchell No that json can not be parsed correctly. It should be, for ex., `{ "memberOf" : ["groupA", "groupB"] }`

Comment: @Brizio can you get it to deserialize though? Like a round trip?

Comment: @JohnMitchell Serializing and deserializing a List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> works both ways, but the format needs to be the one I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see it should not be possible using the JavaScriptSerializer. The only way for customizing its behavior is by means of a [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class, that will allow you to customize the serialization/deserialization process. Unfortunately both methods will pass an IDictionary for the properties, therefore the duplicated names are already merged. You might want to look into either a different format for your JSON or a different serialization library such as [JSON.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) which is way more customizable.